Question about LASSO, RMSE, and Standardization
I have a question about doing LASSO in R using glmnet. It's kind of a conceptual question; I learned that we should interpret RMSE after performing glmnet, to check the performance of the model. Lower RMSE is better, though I still don't get what's the threshold.
I also learned that it is essential to standardize IVs before performing LASSO. Additionally, we can standardize DV too, for better inference. When I didn't standardize the DV, rmse was 2.55. When I standardize the DV, rmse is 0.90.
I learned that this means that the model performs poorly. I really don't understand why this is happening- does it mean performing OLS is better choice?
clarify what's RMSE meaning in LASSO

The RMSE of what?

@Dave  RMSE of LASSO using glmnet. I used rmse_vec()function

If you want people help you, you should put more details on what you are aiming for. Here it's hard to give you an answer.

Is one RMSE calculated by comparing predictions to the original data, while the other is calculated by comparing predictions to standardized data?

@Dave Yes! You are correct

What happens when you back-transform the predictions made on the scaled scale? After all, you (probably) don’t want to predict on the scaled scale but on the original scale.
